# Install VMWare tools disabled on Guest VM

Tags: vmware

I'm trying to install a Windows 7 on a VM in Ubuntu, but the "Install VMware Tools" button is faded.

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 3):

NVM I Fixed it, I removed the floppy drive and added a second CD drive.

Comment: This is some cringe. Took me an hour to come to this.